# Changing the "Language for non-Unicode programs" individually

Tags: windows-xp, unicode

Is it possible to run a program with non-default value of the "[Language for non-Unicode programs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_select_language_version.mspx?mfr=true)" system option? I have an application (Wolfram *Mathematica* 8) which behaviour critically depends on this system option. On the other hand, I cannot change it globally because I have other applications which require the default value of this option to run properly...

P.S. I use Windows XP SP3 Russian.

Comment: Post it in superuser or in Mma.se . Here it will be most probably closed as off topic. (only programming questions)

Answer (score 1):

[AppLocale](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13209)

[Служебная программа Microsoft AppLocale](http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=13209)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for *Mathematica*. Are there other solutions?